# Can the user of an app see what's in the https packets?

Tags: android, security, https

If I exchange https packets between a server and an Android client, is it easy for the user of the android client to get whatever is in the encrypted traffic? Should I consider all such traffic unsafe if the safety is dependent on the user not being able to somehow read what's in the https packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways the contents of an HTTPS packet could be inspected. A [man-in-the-middle-attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) could compromise HTTPS traffic. With man-in-the-middle, a malicious third party intercepts messages between two parties trying to communicate and inspects or alters their messages. With HTTPS, the third party acts as a proxy, and would need to trick one party into trusting a certificate they issue so the third party can decrypt their SSL connection.

A user could also proxy their own traffic before it is sent to your server. Using tools like [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) or [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/) a user can set up a proxy to intercept their own traffic. The user could see the contents of every request they send, as well as every response from the server, even with an HTTPS connection. With an intercepting proxy they could even alter the requests their Android device makes before it's sent to your server. In essence, the user uses a man-in-the-middle attack on their self.

**In short, the user can find ways to easily see the HTTPS traffic to and from their own device.**

Comment: The solution is to pin the server certificate in the client device, that way a MITM attack can be avoided.

Comment: Certificate pinning is a good defense. There are ways, however, to bypass certificate pining, like Android-SSL-TrustKiller https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller. Since we're considering the app user as the potential attacker, they will have full access to the device to use such tools. Certificate pinning can be defeated, but it makes the task much more difficult and demands a more technically savvy user to compromise.

Comment: Also relevant: BlackHat 2012 presentation on pentesting applications that use certificate pinning: http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Turbo/Diquet/BH_US_12_Diqut_Osborne_Mobile_Certificate_Pinning_Slides.pdf

Comment: And don't leave out ["rubber hose cryptanalysis"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/10/rubber_hose_cry.html). There are very few ways to be completely secure but that does not mean not to use the well accepted methods of reducing the attack window. Pinning the server certificate greatly improves the security.

Comment: The attacks linked all require rooting/jailbreaking the device which is viable but has a couple of limitations: access to an unlocked device and substantial skills. Further it is acknowledged that protecting information on a device from the user is very difficult.

Comment: @zaph, it's a hobby project about a very simple turn based multiplayer game, so "rubber hose cryptanalysis" isn't really what I'm afraid of :P The biggest problem I can see is cheating because as it is now it's dependent on game information being sent in the beginning of a game session which give all the information needed to win without the intended effort.

Comment: If this is a hobby project game, then I agree with zaph's suggestion, certificate pinning would be a good way to stop cheating.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple proxy attacks where the user can reasonably easily, with some skill, view the unencrypted data.

To avoid these relatively simple attacks use https with the server supporting TLS 1.2 and perfect forward secrecy (current Best Practice) and pin the certificate in the app. That will rule out the easy proxy attacks such as Charles Proxy.

Note: It is very hard to completely secure anything on a device from the owner.